# Use of undeclared identifier 'glutBitmapString' in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, glut

I am using Xcode. I have already linked OpenGL.framework and GLUT.framework.

Here is my code btw

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

void func(){
     glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      
     const unsigned char str[100] = {"some message"};
     glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
     glRasterPos2f(0.0, 0.0); 
     glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, str); //Use of undeclared identifier 'glutBitmapString'
     glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(func);
    glutMainLoop();
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using FreeGLUT or some other GLUT implementation that supports [`glutBitmapString()`](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/FG_3_2_2/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h#L185-L186):

> [3.4 Differences from GLUT 3.7](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#Background)
>
> ...
>
> 3.4.5 String Rendering
>
> **New functions have been added to render full character strings (including carriage returns) rather than rendering one character at a time.** More functions return the widths of character strings and the font heights, in pixels for bitmapped fonts and in OpenGL units for the stroke fonts.

`glutBitmapString()` is not a part of [the GLUT 3.X spec](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node75.html), which only has character-by-character drawing functions.